# Running a loop with a custom query string on a custom page template

Tags: loop, page-template

I made a custom page with a template that is just a loop with custom query string for a list of posts from a specific category but when I view the page it only shows one post with the title being the title of the page. I don't understand why it doesn't return the loop of posts. What am I doing wrong? Heres the page template.

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: music videos
  */
?>
 <div class="panes-feed">
   <ul>
    <?php
     global $query_string;
     query_posts($query_string .'&posts_per_page=10&cat=3&orderby=asc'); ?> 
    <?php $i=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++; ?>
      <li>
      <a style="display:block;height:100%" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"  rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent Link to', 'buddypress' ) ?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
           <?php
              foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
              echo "<div id='$category->slug' style='margin-right:4px;position:absolute;right:0;display:block' title='$category->cat_name'></div>";
             }
           ?>
        <span class="video-thumb">
          <span class="video-clip">
            <span class="video-clip-inner">
               <?php $video_code = tube_getcustomfield('video_code',get_the_ID()); if($video_code) { ?>
                <img src="<?php $thumb = get_youtube_screen_link( $video_code, 'default' ) ?>" width="120" height="90" />
               <?php } else { ?>
                <?php echo_first_image ($post->ID); ?>
               <?php } ?>
               <span class="vertical-align"></span>
               </span></span></span>
                <div style="display:inline-block;width:225px">
                <h3 style="color:#e2e2e2"><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 
                <p><?php echo time_ago(); ?><?php _e( ' in', 'buddypress' ) ?> <span><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span> </p>
                <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) {  ?><p style="font-size:11px;margin-bottom:0px"><?php the_views(); ?> </p><?php } ?>
                </div>

     </a>
  </li>                                             
<?php if($i%1==0) : ?><div class="clear"></div><?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the `$query_string` defined?

Comment: line 8 right? That loop works when I place it directly on my index page. For some reason on a custom page it doesn't.

Comment: Add `global $query_string;` on top of your template (after the comment).

Comment: That didn't change anything which is weird because the wordpress codex says it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove $query_string from the template. the Quesry string contains params specific to your page...

your loop should look like this:

```
<?php
query_posts("posts_per_page=10&cat=3&orderby=asc&paged=".get_query_var('paged'));
if (have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
       the_post();
       <!-- your custom data here -->
       the_title();
       the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: For some reason thats only returning one post for the category.

Comment: Odd it only returns one post on the page but when it call it to the homepage with ajax it returns all the posts. Im gonna call that a win since that's all I needed it for.